# Assign schema to pa.Table.from_pandas()

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

Im getting this error when transforming a pandas.DF to parquet using pyArrow:

```
ArrowInvalid('Error converting from Python objects to Int64: Got Python object of type str but can only handle these types: integer
```

To find out which column is the problem I made a new df in a for loop, first with the first column and for each loop adding another column. I realized that the error is in a column of `dtype: object` that starts with 0s, I guess that's why pyArrow wants to convert the column to `int` but fails because other values are `UUID`

Im trying to pass a schema: (not sure if this is the way to go)

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema, preserve_index=False)
```

where schema is: `df.dtypes`

Comment: perhaps share the output of `df.head()` and `df.info()` or provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Carlos have you tried converting the column to one of the pandas types listed here https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html?

Can you post the output of df.dtypes?

If changing the pandas column type doesn't help you can define a pyarrow schema to pass in.

```
fields = [
    pa.field('id', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('secondaryid', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('date', pa.timestamp('ms')),
]

my_schema = pa.schema(fields)

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(sample_df, schema=my_schema, preserve_index=False)
```

More information here:

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.from_pandas
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.schema.html

Comment: storing an ID as int (in current pandas) can pose problems when there are missing values (loss of information when converting to float with long IDs) or the IDs become very long (20+ chars)

Comment: Hi Alexander, I want to keep the column df dtypes as object due to other operations and transformations that are done latter on. Im trying the pa.schema, if that doesn't work then I will coerce the df dtypes.

Comment: While writing parquet it does not actual infer to schema. I have None in columns and I want to convert them to int64 but it converts column to float while writing but in table.schema it shows int64